# Ext Js SegmentedButton value in form submit

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to get Ext.SegmentedButton value in form submit?

```
        {
        xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
        name: 'title',
        items: [
            {text: 'Mr', value: 'Mr'},
            {text: 'Mrs', value: 'Mrs'},
            {text: 'Madam', value: 'Madam'},
            {text: 'Ms', value: 'Ms'},
            {text: 'Dr', value: 'Dr'},
            {text: 'Prof', value: 'Prof'},          
            ],
        },
```

Comment: What do you mean get the value? There is a separate value for each button. Do you mean get the value of the buttons that are pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the segmented button, [you can just query it for elements that are pressed](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)

```
segmented.down('[pressed=true]');
```

Full example  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ctk

```
var segmented = Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
    name: 'title',
    items: [
           {text: 'Mr', value: 'Mr'},
           {text: 'Mrs', value: 'Mrs'},
           {text: 'Madam', value: 'Madam'},
           {text: 'Ms', value: 'Ms'}
    ],
});


var container = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Get Selected',
        handler: function() {
            var selectedBtn = segmented.down('[pressed=true]');
            alert(selectedBtn && selectedBtn.value);
        }
    }],
    items: segmented
});
```